# does PyCharm read the zsh environment by default

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm, zsh

Today when I start the python project in PyCharm, I found the environment fetched failed:

```
db_conn = os.environ.get('CLUSTER_POSTGRESQL_CONN')
```

this statement get None from environment. Yesterday it works fine, I check the environment in terminal:

```
➜  ai-web git:(main) ✗ env|grep "POST"
CLUSTER_POSTGRESQL_CONN=postgresql://postgres:123456@reddwarf-postgresql.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local:5432/dolphin
```

and I already add the environment variable into `.zshrc`. why the PyCharm code could not get the environment? what should I do to fix it? does PyCharm read zsh environment by default? This is the system debug configuration:

[image]

Now I found the PyCharm only read part of the system environment and I tried to restart the PyCharm, the environment still difference with the value I saw in terminal.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `os.environ['CLUSTER_POSTGRESQL_CONN']` ?   What if you just `print(os.environ)` (it's just a dictionary like object) is there anything there.  Are by any chance using a python virtualenv, pipenv or pyenv? (Note pycharm uses venvs if it can).  In pycharm open a python terminal and then an OS terminal and run python and see what values are in there.

Comment: `.zshrc` only applies to the shell that sources it, and Mac applications are not typically started from *any* shell session, being launched by `launchd` directly.

Comment: Please definie what you mean by _zsh **environment**_. If you are talking about environment variables, they are unrelated to zsh, but simply passed from parent to child process. If you mean internal zsh-specific definitions (zsh shell variables, functions and the like), they have no meaning in Python and it does not make sense for "reading" them.

Comment: The example you posted, is a bit unclear. If you see `CLUSTER_POSTGRESQL_CONN` defined in your shell as environment variable, and if you start PyCharm **from this very same shell** (you don't mention this in your question), the environment variable will initially also be available by PyCharm. This is a general mechanism on how child processes are spawned. Of course PyCharm (I don't know this application) is free to change its environment.

Answer (score 1):

> does PyCharm read the zsh environment by default

The short answer is that PyCharm does not read zsh environment by default.

However if you launch Python script from PyCharm terminal, or any other terminal, it will have the shell environment available.